# jsf and primefaces update problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page with two forms (pseudo-code below).

First form is for a user and has text fields and a table of phone numbers, and a link for 
adding a new phone number.

Second form is the p:dialog that shows the form for adding a phone number to the list.

The problem I have is after the p:dialog closes, I want the list is not getting updated.  If I put the p:dialog tag inside the first form, the list does get updated but there are two separate forms because I need their contents to be validated in separate actions.

SHORT VERSION OF MY QUESTION: The p:dialog has an attr update="phonesPanel" but phonePanel is in a different form; how do I do something like update="personForm.phonesPanel" so it updates the list which is in a different form?

```
<h:form id="personForm">

  <p:messages />

  <h:inputText label="Full Name" value="... />

  <p:commandLink value="Add Phone Number" onclick="dlg.show();" />

  <h:panelGrid id="phonesPanel" columns="1" style="width:100%" >
    <h:dataTable id="phonesTable">
      // ...
    </h:dataTable>
  </h:panelGrid>

</h:form>


<h:form>

  <p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
     <p:messages />
     <h:inputText label="Phone Number" value="... />
     <p:commandButton value="Add Phone Number" update="phonesPanel"   
       actionListener="#{handler.doAddPhoneNumber}" 
       oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)"/>  
  </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The answer is: update="personForm:phonesPanel"

Thanks all!

Answer (score 7):

Other thing you can do is set the "prependId" form attribute to "false":

```
<h:form prependId="false">
```

This way you don't need to use the nested id's and might use:

```
update="phonesPanel"
```

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that update="personForm:phonesPanel" works without a ":" before personForm.
This should be the correct one:

```
update=":personForm:phonesPanel"
```