# Correct way to update message-field when using JSF and Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, updates

There is an another question just about that, but I couldn't solve my problem with that. 
[jsf and primefaces update problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250370/jsf-and-primefaces-update-problem)

What is the correct level to start with :? I just want to update messagePanel-messages, what is wrong with that. I have tried 5 different solutions, but no success.

```
<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.editXTZ_title} - #{XTZBean.username} - -->: #{RmaBean.selectedRma.rma}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
        <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="formi">
            <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{XTZBean.activeIndex}">  
                <p:tab title="Muokkaa">
```

......more code and then

```
                <p:tab title="Avainsanat">  

                        <p:panelGrid id="avainsanaGrid" style="margin-top:20px;" styleClass="noBorders">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>


<p:row rendered="#{XTZBean.suljettu}">
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column><p:commandButton value="Tallenna" id="btnAvainsana" process="@this,avainsana" update="avainsanaGrid, :messagePanel"  
                                                           actionListener="#{XTZBean.talletaAvainsana}" style="width: 210px;"/></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                                <p:column></p:column>
                            </p:row> 
                         </p:panelGrid>  
                    </p:tab>
```

Thanks!
Sami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information given so far (and assuming that the `<ui:insert name="body">` is not by itself in another `NamingContainer` component), the `:messagePanel` is right.

But the `<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel">` is not at the right place. It's completely outside the template definition and thus totally ignored. It has to be placed inside any of the `<ui:define>`.

E.g.

```
<ui:define name="body">
    <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
        <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:form id="formi">
        ...
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I got a javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":messagePanel" referenced from "j_idt6:formi:j_idt12:btnAvainsana".

Comment: Did you fix the template? Well, if you still get this exception, then there's apparently another `NamingContainer` as parent of `<ui:insert name="body">` which has according to the exception message most likely the autogenerated ID `j_idt6`. Give it a fixed ID and use `:someId:messagePanel` instead. See also the 1st "See also" link in my answer for details.

Comment: Give your form prepend id false <h:form id="form" prependId="false">

Comment: @KeremBaydoğan: no, that won't fix it. The messages are not placed inside the form.

Comment: @ BalusC Yes I fixed it as well. <ui:define name="body">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form id="formi">
                 
                <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{RmaBean.activeIndex}">  
                    <p:tab title="edit">  
                        <p:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px;" styleClass="noBorders">

Comment: @balusC Yes I read it. What can be that another naming container?<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.editRma_title_muokkaa} - #{RmaBean.username}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
       
        <ui:define name="body" id="body">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:form id="formi">

Comment: As said, it's the parent of `<ui:insert name="body">`. It's there in your master template.

Comment: :j_idt6:messagePanel AND :templateForm:messagePanel works fine. In template:<h:body>
        <h:form id="templateForm">                                 <div id="content" class="center_content">
                <ui:insert name="body">Content</ui:insert>
            </div> Is this BTW correct way to implement template? Two forms now I think?? Thanks to everyone for helping me!

Comment: As said, you should give the component which is identified by `j_idt6` a **fixed** ID. Otherwise this autogenerated ID will change when you add another component before the particular component and you'd need to fix all those `update` identifiers again. By the way, nesting forms is illegal in HTML. Non-ajax buttons will fail to work this way.

Comment: @ BalusC That's why I was asking. I haven't implemented that template so  I think that I will delete that form from the template. It should be usefull and like you said, it's illegal. Thanks for helping everyone!!

Comment: Report it to the template's author so that it gets a fixed ID. As to the nested form, the problem can also be the other way round: perhaps you shouldn't be placing the `<h:form id="formi">` in the template client.